How can I get a portlet to fill the empty space instead of starting at the last vertical ending position of another portlet
So in the picture below you will see how my portlets are rendering, this sizing issue is due to the data within them which is hidden here for business purposes. I would essentially like to have one portlet or the other take the place of the empty space instead of leaving giant gaps between them.

